# Can I use p5.js to create playable ads for Google, Facebook and Unity ads?

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I am currently working on building a 2D playable ad for a game and p5.js looks like the perfect library for my use case. In order to check whether it would work, I wrote a very simple inline code (using [p5.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js)) to test on Facebook playable ad preview tool.

The file works perfectly on the browser (both the desktop and phone browser), however on the tool it fails on the case:
`Asset cannot contain any JavaScript redirects.`
It also displays some js code on the phone emulator screen of the tool.

What does this mean and how do I fix the issue? I'm sorry but I'm new to web development and javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated.
[This](https://jsfiddle.net/salmaan25/4wnrf15e/) is my code in jsfiddle and [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/playable-preview/) is the link to the Facebook playable ad preview tool.

[Here's](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js) the link to the uncompressed version of p5.js.

Comment: Thank you for the link to jsFiddle but that is minified and incomprehensible code. Not much help at all. I'm guessing that you have a location redirect somewhere in the JavaScript (I can see references to `location.href=`). It's likely these that are being flagged.

Comment: Thanks, I will put a link to the uncompressed version. Also, I checked and p5.min.js has 6 results for ```location.href``` and p5.js has more than 8. Would you say that playable ads can't be made in p5.js?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.